# Pass every attribute of model in ng-repeat to directive isolate-scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using a directive with an ng-repeat

```
<page ng-repeat='page in pages' id='{{page.id}}' title='{{page.title}}'></page>
```

And my directive :

```
app.directive('page', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            id: '@',
            title: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/tpl/page.html',
        controller: 'PageController'
});
```

Is there any way to avoid having to pass in manually all the attributes into the directive's isolate scope ? My goal would be to populate the directive's scope automatically with every attribute in the "page" object.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the whole page object.  [Directives Guid](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

html:

```
<page ng-repeat='page in pages' page-object='page'></page>
```

js:

```
app.directive('page', function(){
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        pageObject: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/tpl/page.html',
    controller: 'PageController'
});
```